# Automated build uploads to test flight / itunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, testflight

Is there a path for our CI server to automate build uploads to itunesConnect / testFlight now that they've merged?

I know this is possible with hockeyApp but I wasn't sure if the new official apple solution also supports it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Shenzhen will allow this

https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen